# Keycloak : Access token expiry time

Tags: api, go, keycloak, access-token

Is it possible to modify access token/refresh token expiry time in Keycloak using code?

I have checked documentation but there is no endpoint which can be used to modify token settings.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no specific endpoint for that. There is, however, endpoints that allows one to change the Realm and Client settings that would affect the access and refresh token expiration time.

Comment: What are endpoints which can affect access and refresh token expiry time ?

Comment: PUT /{realm} and PUT /{realm}/clients/{id} from https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource